# Translating from c to mips assembly

Tags: c, mips

I have spent the greater part of today trying to properly translate this c code to mips and I'm struggling on the formatting and the second half of the pattern. The second part of the pattern breaks in a new way everytime i make a small change to the code. Im lookin to learn so any other tips regarding mips and mistakes made would help a ton.

```
.data

prompt: .asciiz "Please enter the number of Columns: "
s: .asciiz " "
n: .asciiz "\n"



.text
main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall
move $s0, $v0 #$s0 holds N
li $s3, 0   #$s3 holds I
li $s4, 0   #$s4 holds J
li $s5, 1   #s5 holds K
add $s2, $zero, $s0 #holds N-i

li $s2, 0
add $s2, $zero, $s0 
addi $s2, $s2, 1
sub $s2, $s2, $s3

for1:

blt  $s0,$s3, bottom

addi $s3, $s3, 1


li $s4, 0

j for2

for2:
blt  $s3, $s4,for3

li $v0, 4
la $a0, s
syscall

addi $s4, $s4, 1
li $s2, 0
add $s2, $zero, $s0 
addi $s2, $s2, 1
sub $s2, $s2, $s3
li $s5 , 1
j for2

for3:
blt $s2, $s5,newline1
li $t0, 0
add $t0, $zero, $s5
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t0
syscall
li $t0, 0
addi $s5, $s5, 1


j for3

bottom:
li $s3, 1   #$s3 holds I
li $s4, 1   #$s4 holds J
li $s5, 1   #s5 holds K
add $s2, $zero, $s0 #holds N-i

addi $s2, $s2, 1
sub $s2, $s2, $s3

for4:
blt  $s0,$s3, exit

addi $s3, $s3, 1
li $s4, 0
li $s2, 0
add $s2, $zero, $s0 
sub $s2, $s2, $s3

j for5


for5:
blt  $s2, $s4,for6

li $v0, 4
la $a0, s
syscall

addi $s4, $s4, 1
li $t2, 1
addi $t2, $s3, 0

li $s5 , 1
j for5

for6:
blt $t2, $s5,newline2

li $t3, 2
addi $t3,$s3, 0
sub $t3,$t3,$s5
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t3
syscall
addi $s5, $s5, 1

j for6

newline1:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, n
syscall
j for1
newline2:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, n
syscall
j for4

exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

here is the c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   

int main(void) {   
int n;                                           

printf("Please enter the number of columns:");     // [0.25 mark]   
scanf("%d",&n);                                    // [0.25 mark] 

 //printing the upper part of the pattern.   
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){                              // [4 mark] 
for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {                         // [4 mark] 
printf(" ");                               // [0.25 mark] 
}   
for(int k=1;k<=n-i;k++){                       // [4 mark] 
printf("%d", k);                           // [0.5 mark] 
}   
printf("\n");                                  // [0.25 mark] 
}   

//printing the lower part of the pattern. 
for(int i=1;i<n;i++){                              // [4 mark] 
for(int j=1;j<n-i;j++){                        // [4 mark] 
printf(" ");                               // [0.25 mark] 
 }   
for(int k=1;k<=i+1;k++){                       // [4 mark] 
printf("%d", (i+2 - k));                   // [0.5 mark] 
 }   
printf("\n");                                  // [0.25 mark] 
} 

return 0;                                          // [0.25 mark] 
}
```

Any help with this is greatly apprciated!

*update* working code

```
.data

prompt: .asciiz "Please enter the number of Columns: "
s: .asciiz " "
n: .asciiz "\n"



.text
main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall
move $s0, $v0 #$s0 holds N
li $s3, 0   #$s3 holds I
li $s4, 0   #$s4 holds J
li $s5, 1   #s5 holds K
add $s2, $zero, $s0 #holds N-i

li $s2, 0
add $s2, $zero, $s0 
addi $s2, $s2, 1
sub $s2, $s2, $s3

for1:

ble  $s0,$s3, bottom




li $s4, 0

j for2

for2:
blt  $s3, $s4,for3

li $v0, 4
la $a0, s
syscall

addi $s4, $s4, 1

li  $s2, 0
add $s2, $s0, 0
sub $s2, $s2, $s3
li $s5 , 1

j for2

for3:
blt $s2, $s5,newline1
li $t0, 0
add $t0, $zero, $s5
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t0
syscall
li $t0, 0
addi $s5, $s5, 1


j for3


bottom:
li $s3,1    #$s3 holds I
li $s4, 1   #$s4 holds J
li $s5, 1   #s5 holds K
li  $s2, 0
add $s2, $s0, 0 #holds N-i
j for4

for4:
blt $s0, $s3, exit

li  $s2, 0
add $s2, $s0, 0
sub $s2, $s2, $s3



li $s4, 1




j for5

for5:
blt  $s2, $s4,for6

li $v0, 4
la $a0, s
syscall
addi $s4, $s4, 1

li $t1, 1
li $t2, 2
add $t1, $t1, $s3
add $t2, $t2,$s3 

li $s5, 1

j for5

for6:

blt $t1, $s5,newline2



li $t3, 0
sub $t3, $t2,$s5
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t3
syscall
addi $s5, $s5, 1


j for6


newline1:
addi $s3, $s3, 1
li $v0, 4
la $a0, n
syscall
j for1
newline2:
addi $s3, $s3, 1
li $v0, 4
la $a0, n
syscall

j for4

exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: If the problem is solved, post the solution as an answer. Otherwise the system will not consider it solved. Also, explain the solution so it will be useful to others

Comment: I don't follow Assembler, but it looks like this might be "single purpose" - only reproducing the one pattern that starts "54321"... What if the project were to use all 10 digits, or perhaps all 26 single-case letters?

Comment: Also, can you explain the "mark" comments? Why didn't you transfer them to the assembly? The comments should transfer, so that the translation is easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the proper solution to the question. The mark comments are for grading purposes as this is an assignment. The issue I ran to was I was incrementing I within the first for loop moving it to the newline function helped fix the issue I was having. The pattern was only meant to reach 1-9. If there are any new questions ill try my best to answer them.

```
.data

prompt: .asciiz "Please enter the number of Columns: "
s: .asciiz " "
n: .asciiz "\n"



.text
main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt  # asks column amount
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall
move $s0, $v0 #$s0 holds N
li $s3, 0   #$s3 holds I
li $s4, 0   #$s4 holds J    #declares locations for variables
li $s5, 1   #s5 holds K
add $s2, $zero, $s0 #holds N-i

li $s2, 0
add $s2, $zero, $s0 
addi $s2, $s2, 1    # sets up n-i
sub $s2, $s2, $s3

for1:   # first for loop

ble  $s0,$s3, bottom # break when less than to bottom func




li $s4, 0 # resets j to 0 eveery iteration

j for2 #jumps to second loop

for2:
blt  $s3, $s4,for3 # breaks when less than to for3
    
    li $v0, 4   #prints spaces
la $a0, s
syscall

addi $s4, $s4, 1 # increments J

li  $s2, 0
add $s2, $s0, 0
sub $s2, $s2, $s3   #updates n-i
li $s5 , 1

j for2 #repeats loop

for3:
blt $s2, $s5,newline1   #break when less than to newline1
li $t0, 0
add $t0, $zero, $s5
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t0           #prints numbers (K)
syscall
li $t0, 0
addi $s5, $s5, 1


j for3 # repeats loop


bottom:
li $s3,1    #$s3 holds I
li $s4, 1   #$s4 holds J    #sets variables for second 3 loops
li $s5, 1   #s5 holds K
li  $s2, 0
add $s2, $s0, 0 #holds N-i
j for4

for4:
blt $s0, $s3, exit  #break to exit when less than

li  $s2, 0
add $s2, $s0, 0
sub $s2, $s2, $s3   #sets up n-i



li $s4, 1   #sets j to 1




j for5  

for5:
blt  $s2, $s4,for6          #break to sixth loop

li $v0, 4
la $a0, s       #prints spaces
syscall
addi $s4, $s4, 1    #increments j

li $t1, 1
li $t2, 2                   #setting up i+1 and i+2
add $t1, $t1, $s3
add $t2, $t2,$s3 

li $s5, 1   #sets k to 1

j for5  #repeats loop

for6:

blt $t1, $s5,newline2 #breaks to newline 2 func



li $t3, 0
sub $t3, $t2,$s5            #prints numbers
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t3
syscall
addi $s5, $s5, 1


j for6  #repeats loops


newline1:
addi $s3, $s3, 1 #increments i
li $v0, 4
la $a0, n   #prints new line
syscall
j for1 # jumps to for loop 1
newline2:
addi $s3, $s3, 1 #increments i 
li $v0, 4   #prints new line
la $a0, n
syscall

j for4  #jumps to for loop 4

exit:   #ends program
li $v0, 10
syscall
```